# Session Object Not Returning On Page Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session

So In Default.master.cs PageLoad I have the following:

```
contObj = Session["Contributor"] == null ? null : (Contributor)Session["Contributor"];
if (contObj == null)
{
    Session["Contributor"] = new Contributor
    {
        ID = id,
        Name = name,
        Email = email
    };
}
```

In Default.aspx.cs I'm trying to get the object by doing this on a button click event:\

```
contObj = (Contributor)Session["Contributor"];
```

However this is causing the following exception!
object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Could you please elaborate?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure the session variable in set, if you doing in if(Page.IsPostBack)

Comment: This is contained within `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` inside PageLoad in the MasterPage.

Comment: So you are getting session in master page?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the session in Master page - Should i just move the code block from master to default.aspx? - I should mention that it works on Firefox but not on IE - Which is a very weird issue.

Comment: Very strange behavior check if in page tag you have EnableSessionState="true" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your EnableSessionState="true" in the page tag of default.aspx

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here since he's retrieving the Session object in the click event of a button. That should fire after the Page Load of the MasterPage.

Comment: Thanks Adil for the quick response. But could you please take a look at what Kristof said? Thanks.